# Facing issue of single quotes in fckeditor

Tags: php

I want to enter single quotes in database through fckeditor..but My code is not work for me.

"insert into $user
            (id,question,option1,option2,option3,option4,correctAnswer,category,section,chapter)
            VALUES
            ("
            . ",$newstd," . 
            "','". htmlspecialchars($_POST['FCKeditor0'],ENT_QUOTES) .
            "','" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['FCKeditor1'],ENT_QUOTES) .
            "','" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['FCKeditor2'],ENT_QUOTES) .
            "','" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['FCKeditor3'],ENT_QUOTES) .
            "','" . htmlspecialchars($_POST['FCKeditor4'],ENT_QUOTES) . 
            "','" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['correctans'],ENT_QUOTES) . 
            "'," . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['MyRadio'],ENT_QUOTES) .
            "'," . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['section'],ENT_QUOTES) .
            "'," . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['chapter'],ENT_QUOTES) .
            ")";

Thank You ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
insert into $user(id,question,option1,option2,option3,option4,correctAnswer,category,section,chapter)
values
(
"'.$newstd.'",
'".htmlspecialchars([\'$question1\'],ENT_QUOTES)."'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"insert into $user (id,question,option1,option2,option3,option4,correctAnswer,category,section,chapter) VALUES ("'$newstd'" , "',
    '" . htmlspecialchars(['$question1'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',
    '" . htmlspecialchars(['$question2'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',
    '" . htmlspecialchars(['$question3'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',
    '" . htmlspecialchars(['$question4'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',
    '" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['correctans'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',
    " . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['MyRadio'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',
    " . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['section'],ENT_QUOTES) . "',
    " . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['chapter'],ENT_QUOTES) .
")";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like

```
"insert into $user(id,question,option1,option2,option3,option4,correctAnswer,category,section,chapter)
            VALUES
            (
            '".$newstd."' ,
            '" . htmlspecialchars($question1,ENT_QUOTES) ."'
            )";
```

You have problem with `double quotes`

Answer (score 0):

Correct code is

```
"insert into $user (id,question,option1,option2,option3,option4,correctAnswer,category,section,chapter) VALUES ('$newstd','" . htmlspecialchars($question1, ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($question2, ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($question3, ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($question4, ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['correctans'], ENT_QUOTES) . "'," . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['MyRadio'], ENT_QUOTES) . "'," . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['section'], ENT_QUOTES) . "','" . htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['chapter'], ENT_QUOTES) . "')";
```

Answer (score 0):

To maintain the readability to the code, you can use it this way

```
$question1= htmlspecialchars(['$question1'],ENT_QUOTES);
$question2= htmlspecialchars(['$question2'],ENT_QUOTES);
$question3= htmlspecialchars(['$question3'],ENT_QUOTES);
$question4= htmlspecialchars(['$question4'],ENT_QUOTES);
$correctans= htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['correctans'],ENT_QUOTES);
$MyRadio= htmlspecialchars([$_REQUEST['MyRadio'],ENT_QUOTES);
$section= htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['section'],ENT_QUOTES);
$chapter= htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['chapter'],ENT_QUOTES);

"insert into $user (id,question,option1,option2,option3,option4,correctAnswer,category,section,chapter) VALUES (' ','$newstd','$quertion1','$quertion2','$quertion3','$quertion4','$correctans','$MyRadio','$section','$chapter')";
```